# Matching a file with table in postgres and identify the match level

Tags: java, postgresql, arraylist, match, multiple-columns

I have a table with 4 columns and is loaded with data. The data can range from 1000 to maximum of 2Million.

I get a file (lets say tab separated) as part of daily process with the data for 4 columns. I should prepare a report where for each column match i should increase the Match level.

eg:

file.col1 data exists in db.col1 ; then matchlevel = 1

file.col2 data exists in db.col2 ; then matchlevel = 2

file.col3 data exists in db.col3 ; then matchlevel = 3

file.col4 data exists in db.col4 ; then matchlevel = 4

**Example Data in DB: (all fields are strings)**

```
1367    37991   11111   sometext1
1365    37993   11112   sometext2
1369    34521   sample1 sometext1
1359    76583   sample2 sometext2
```

**Example Data in File: (all fields are strings)**

```
1367    37991   11111   sometext1
1365    8993    sample3  sometext5
1369    34521   sample4 sometext6
1359    76583   sample2 sometext7
1651    875637  notpresentindb    notpresentindb
```

The output should be

```
id from file    Match Level

1367            Max  (all fields match in db)
1365            Low  (only column1 matches 
1369            Med  (column1 and 2 match)
1359            High (First 3 columns match)
1651            No Match (no columns match)
```

Currently, I am doing this Java. Declared 4 arraylists and copied all the data in the columns to arraylists and using apache collections to find if the each column data exists in each of the 4 arraylists for test purposes. 
But this is redflagged because we need to load 4 columns of data with 1 million records and server memory may be all consumed.

Sample code below: 
    Arraylist1,Arraylist2,Arraylist3,Arraylist4 are defined 
before below code and loaded with data from db.

```
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] temp;
                temp = sCurrentLine.split("\\t");
                value = "no match";
                valueInt = 0;
                if(arraylist1.contains(temp[0])){
                    value = "low";
                    int retval=arraylist1.indexOf(temp[0]);
                    if (arraylist2.get(retval).equals(temp[1]))  {                          
                        value = "med";

                        if (arraylist3.get(retval).equals(temp[2])){
                            value = "High";

                            if (arraylist4.get(retval).equals(temp[3])) {
                                value = "Max";

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I tried below two answers provided and both worked as breeze. I am very thankful to you guys.

Comment: I appreciate your decision to delete that other question. And for the record - people here want to help. But not every problem can be broken down to fit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Postgresql 9.1 you can use foreign data wrappers to view files as tables. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/file-fdw.html

Once you can see your Csv as a table, you can use SQL power to generate your report.

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    c1 text,
    c2 text,
    c3 text
) ;

CREATE EXTENSION file_fdw;
CREATE SERVER my_csv_server FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_fdw;

CREATE TABLE csv (
    id integer,
    c1 text,
    c2 text,
    c3 text
) 
SERVER my_csv_server 
OPTIONS ( filename '/home/me/data.csv', format 'csv' );

SELECT
     id,
     CASE 
         WHEN t.c1 = csv.c1 AND t.c2 = csv.c2 AND t.c3 = csv.c3 THEN
             'Max'
         WHEN t.c1 = csv.c1 AND t.c2 = csv.c2 THEN
             'High'
         WHEN t.c1 = csv.c1 THEN
             'Mid'
         ELSE
             'Low' -- only id match
    END as report
FROM 
    t JOIN csv USING (id)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do the processing in the database, you need to get the file content into it first. I can think of two ways of doing that:

1. create another table and import the file content into it, e.g. using the `copy` command
2. use a [foreign data wrapper](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigntable.html) to access the file content directly

Once you are able to access the file content through SQL, what you want can be done using a simple outer join:

```
select fc.col1,
       case 
         when fc.col1 = bt.col1 and fc.col2 = bt.col2 and fc.col3 = bt.col3 and fc.col4 = bt.col4 then 'Max'
         when fc.col1 = bt.col1 and fc.col2 = bt.col2 and fc.col3 = bt.col3 then 'High'
         when fc.col1 = bt.col1 and fc.col2 = bt.col2 then 'Med'
         when fc.col1 = bt.col1 then 'Low'
         else 'No Match'
       end as match_level
from file_content fc
  left join base_table bt on fc.col1 = bt.col1;
```

If you also need to identify rows that are in the `base_table` but not contained in the file, you need a `full outer join` rather than a left join:

```
select fc.col1,
       case 
         when fc.col1 = bt.col1 and fc.col2 = bt.col2 and fc.col3 = bt.col3 and fc.col4 = bt.col4 then 'Max'
         when fc.col1 = bt.col1 and fc.col2 = bt.col2 and fc.col3 = bt.col3 then 'High'
         when fc.col1 = bt.col1 and fc.col2 = bt.col2 then 'Med'
         when fc.col1 = bt.col1 then 'Low'
         else 
           case when bt.col1 is null then 'Not in database'
           else 'Not in file'
         end
       end as match_level
from file_content fc
  full join base_table bt on fc.col1 = bt.col1;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1ff38/2